# Find and replace values in a txt-file, using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I am writing a program where I need to prepare a text file for analysis (without the use of specific parsers, etc...).
In a final step, I need to replace all accented characters with their unaccented counterpart, using a dictionary.

As this is a school assignment, please just a reference to what I am missing, no complete codes ;-)

This is what I have written.
The plan was to have all the accented characters replaced in the original file. Instead, I am getting a complete blank file.

Thanks for any help/pointers

```
#  decoding dictionary
decode = {'à': 'a', 'á': 'a', 'ä': 'a', 'é': 'e', 'è': 'e', 'ê': 'e','î': 'i', 'í': 'i', 'ô': 'o', 'ö': 'o', 'ò': 'o', 'ó': 'o',
'ù': 'u', 'ú': 'u', 'ü': 'u', 'ç': 'c', 'ß': 'b', 'ñ': 'n'}


#  Open the source file
f = open('spanish4.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
text_input = f.read()

#  read lines in the input file
for line in text_input:

    #  compare input text to dictionary and replace if key is found
    for key in decode:
        if key in line:
            line.replace('d_key','d_value')
f.close()
```

Comment: I would take a close look at [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate)

Comment: `text_input = f.read()` is the problem

Comment: `line.replace('d_key','d_value')` replaces literal strings, not variables with those names

Comment: There are several problems here.  First, you are looking for the literal string "d_key", which of course does not exist in your text.  Next, you are only iterating through the keys, not the values.  Third, `line.replace` RETURNS the new line, it doesn't change it in place.  (You can't change a string.)  Fourth, you are not writing the new lines anywhere.  Fifth, as soon as you do `open('spanish4.txt','w+')`, the file is erased.  You need to open one file for reading, and another file for writing.  Also, you should be using `f.readlines()`, not `f.read()`, which reads the file as one string.

Comment: As Tim said, there are a bunch of problems here. Sorry, but we're not here to debug your code for you. If it's not obvious how to fix it, try breaking it down into one problem at a time (e.g. why is the file empty? next, why aren't characters getting replaced?). See [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341), as well as [ask].

Comment: You might have meant to do `for line in f` instead of `f.read()`. BTW, best practice for opening files is using `with` like `with open(...) as f: for line in f: ...`. It's covered in the official tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 0):

In short: Your code does not replace a line in the original file but in a representation of the file in memory (RAM).

## What your code actually does

With that line you read the whole file from hard disk into the memory (RAM).

```
text_input = f.read()
```

Now you try to iterate over the lines of the file (Problem 1).

```
for line in text_input:
```

Then you (try to) replace the character in the memory (not in the real file).

```
line.replace('d_key','d_value')
```

Now the *main problem*: You never wrote the lines from memory back to a file.

## A possible solution

I think the comments in code are describing it.

```
#  decoding dictionary
decode = {'à': 'a', 'á': 'a', 'ä': 'a', 'é': 'e', 'è': 'e', 'ê': 'e','î': 'i', 'í': 'i', 'ô': 'o', 'ö': 'o', 'ò': 'o', 'ó': 'o',
'ù': 'u', 'ú': 'u', 'ü': 'u', 'ç': 'c', 'ß': 'b', 'ñ': 'n'}

import pathlib  # recommended for filehandling
file_path = pathlib.Path('spanish4.txt')

# open the file...
with file_path.open('w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # read everything into RAM
    text_input = f.read()
# file is closed

# iterate over each key
for key in decode:
    # repeate the replacement as long as the 'key' is
    # present in the original string
    while key in text_input:
        # you need to catch the return value here!
        text_input = text_input.replace(key, decode[key])

# delete the original file
file_path.unlink()
# re-create it
with file_path.open('w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text_input)
```

To understand the `with` please look for context managers in the Python documentation.

Also `str.translate` would be a good place to improve my solution much more.